# Rows of categorical values into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this data set consisting of 34 movies with correspondig dates and values. In the end I want to find a correlation between the time trend and
the values for each movie. The dataset looks something like this:

```
movie;date;value
"Movie1";2012-11-23 11:15:00;25.860000
"Movie1";2012-11-23 11:20:00;25.980000
    .
    .
    .
"Movie34";2012-11-23 11:25:00;25.950000
"Sensor34";2012-11-23 11:30:00;26.010000
"Sensor34";2012-11-23 11:35:00;25.980000
"Sensor34";2012-11-23 11:40:00;26.010000
```

Now, what I want to do is to change this dataset into something like this:

```
 date;Movie1; ... ;Movie34
 2012-11-23 11:15:00;25.860000;26.010000
     .
     .
     .
 2012-11-21 12:15:00;25.860000;24.010000
```

That is, I want that each movie to have a value for each timestamp. Converting categorical values of movie column into 34 columns. And if a timestamp does not exist perhaps fill it with NA. Is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
#filter only Movies if necessary
df = df[df['movie'].str.startswith('Movie')]
df = df.pivot(columns='movie', index='date', values='value')

print (df)
movie                Movie1  Movie34
date                                
2012-11-23 11:15:00   25.86      NaN
2012-11-23 11:20:00   25.98      NaN
2012-11-23 11:25:00     NaN    25.95
```

And if need add rows in `5 minutes` intervals use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
idx = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='5T')
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

Comment: Wow, great! However, worked with pivot_table instead of pivot. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Done! Thanks again.